# use javascript variable outside of class functuon

Tags: javascript

```
 new SomeClass().get(function(resultvariable){
    console.log(resultvariable); // works
 });
```

How could the "resultvariable" be used outside of the class function ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global variable outside of the class. Then assign the value of `resultvariable` to that global variable.

```
var globalVariable;
new SomeClass().get(function(resultvariable){
   console.log(resultvariable); // works
   globalVariable = resultvariable;
});
```

Comment: That usually won't work. The name of the function and the way it takes a callback argument very strongly implies that it is asynchronous. Most of the time, the global won't have a value assigned to it soon enough to achieve the objective.

Comment: Even if it's asynchronous it will get assigned, just not after the call on `.get()`.

Comment: … that's what I said.